# How do I set Python's USER_SITE; do I need to?

Tags: python, macos, configuration, path

I have a Python installation on OS X (10.10; maintained simply with pip) with my site packages in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Apple's packages in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

and the standard Apple Python installation in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
```

I did nothing special to set this up, so I assume it is pretty standard. I install my packages in the site packages directory, and the only thing I have done to "customize" is to prune the Apple packages I don't need or that duplicate ones I maintain in my site packages directory.

Everything works fine, and [all my paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21236384/656912) seem to be just what I'd expect; however I get a confusing result when I

```
python -m site
```

While this shows a `sys.path` that makes sense to me

```
sys.path = [
    '/Users/Rax',
    '/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python', # From PYTHONPATH
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
]
```

I also get

```
USER_BASE: '/Users/Rax/Library/Python/2.7' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/Rax/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

which doesn't make sense to me.

Shouldn't [`USER_SITE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) be `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`? If so, how do I set it (I can't by setting `USER_SITE` to  `/Library/Python/2.7/` because `lib/python/` is added to the path)?

---

This is doubly confusing to me because `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` is correctly added to my `sys.path` (from where I don't know) and because

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.__file__
```

yields `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.pyc`.

Answer (score 3):

The user-site is a machinery is meant "to allow users the local installation of Python packages in their home directory." (see [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)). i.e., it's meant for local user packages, rather than the site-wide installation. If you have multiple users on your system, their user site packages would be separate.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE), we can see that USER_SITE is:

> Path to the user site-packages for the running Python. Can be None if
>   getusersitepackages() hasn’t been called yet. Default value is
>   ~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages for UNIX and non-framework Mac OS
>   X builds, ~/Library/Python/X.Y/lib/python/site-packages for Mac
>   framework builds, and %APPDATA%\Python\PythonXY\site-packages on
>   Windows. This directory is a site directory, which means that .pth
>   files in it will be processed.

(The one for user-base is at the same location)

So to answer your question - I believe they're set up correctly. It's a *different* site packages location than the regular one.

You can also see in the general module documentation it says:

> This file is intended to be created in the user site-packages
>   directory (see below), which is part of sys.path unless disabled by
>   -s. An ImportError will be silently ignored.

So the fact that these paths do not exist doesn't matter.

Also, regarding your question:

> Shouldn't USER_SITE be /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages?

Note that in the docs it says **~**/Library/... - that `~` is replaced with `/Users/Rax/`

You should not worry about the USER_SITE setting at all. If the directory doesn't exist it is not added to the path anyway.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So it's for an *additional* user site packages, beyond the one I have in '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages' (which is standard, and apparently requires no configuration on my part). Correct?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes, as far as I know.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: yes, USER_SITE is meant for *per user* packages, rather than the site-wide installation. If you have *multiple users* on your system, their user site packages would be separate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So if there's just me (and all my packages are in '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'), is the correct (or at least tidy) thing to disable `USER_SITE` (by setting `USER_HOME` to 0)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: you should not worry about the USER_SITE setting at all. If the directory doesn't exist it is not added to the path *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters would you mind if I incorporate your comments into the answer?

Comment: @Korem nope, go ahead!