# Python 'ImportError: No module named' when importing modules across packages

Tags: python, python-packaging

I came across a Python 'ImportError: No module named...' error attempting to import a Python module which resides in another Python package from a module which resides within another Python package. The following image shows the directory structure:

[image: Project directory structure through PyCharm]

It has to be noted that I get this error only when I run the script from my terminal whereas when executing through PyCharm, this script successfully runs. The error when executing from terminal is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "social_networks/linked_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from text_analysis.text_refinement import camel_case_split
ImportError: No module named 'text_analysis'
```

I have tried different ways of importing such as the following without any success:

Method-1:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath('../text_analysis'))
from text_analysis.text_refinement import camel_case_split
```

Method-2:

```
from text_analysis.text_refinement import camel_case_split
```

What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: check this probably help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short version

Change it to:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath('./'))
from text_analysis.text_refinement import camel_case_split
```

Or:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath('./text_analysis'))
from text_refinement import camel_case_split
```

### Long version

I have recreated your project structure on my machine and managed to make it work. Let's go step by step, so that we can figure out what's happening.

First of all, I see you're working on your project in PyCharm. It automatically adds a project root to `PYTHONPATH`. You can read about this in detail in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199382/why-does-pycharm-always-add-contents-root-to-my-pythonpath-and-what-pythonpat). Since PyCharm takes care of path business for you, you do not really need

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath('../text_analysis'))
```

for your code to run. The path will still be added, but it will not be used to locate the package. Try it on your machine. I think you will find it to be true. You can easily check out paths by running

```
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

While this is interesting information, it does not answer your question how to run it from a terminal. To understand why it is not run from the script, lets see what Python paths you would have upon executing the (slightly modified) commands in method-1:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath('../text_analysis'))

try:
    from text_analysis.text_refinement import camel_case_split
    camel_case_split()
except:
    for path in sys.path:
        print(path)

# output:
# ~/text_analysis (where ../text_analysis path points to)
# ~/social-network-interest-engine/social_networks (where your file is)
# ... (several other irrelevant paths) ...
```

We can see that `'../text_analysis'` points one directory *above* what you need. What would happen if we deleted one of the full stops, and instead wrote `'./text_analysis'`? Output seems to be what we need:

```
# output:
# ~/social-network-interest-engine/text_analysis
# ~/social-network-interest-engine/social_networks
```

But we still have not imported the function. We know this because we reach the `except` part, which prints the paths. Looking at import, we can see that we have `text_analysis.text_refinement`. Do we really need to state the directory name if we already added it to the path? No, we do not. If we write

```
from text_refinement import camel_case_split
```

instead, we find that the function has finally been imported. Following this logic, and assuming we wanted to leave `text_analysis.text_refinement` in import statement (for whatever reason), we could add path differently, too:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath('./'))
```

Note, however, that this way of inserting the path is somewhat brittle. The starting location is the path from which you call `python python_file.py` If you navigated to different directory, you would need to adjust `os.path.realpath` accordingly. What you can do instead:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'full/path/to/application/app/folder')
```

Though this assumes that the directory/structure of your project will not change.

For a more in-depth overview of paths and imports, you can read more about importing stuff from different folders [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python), and if you prefer relative path imports, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path/6098238#6098238) is a useful thread. Of course, [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) is also a good place to start.

Comment: Perfect answer... thanks. I am currently allowing the user to set the path of the application directory as an environmental variable.