# Environmental variables set but still cannot execute from command prompt after install Python and PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, environment

Beginner here. Installed Python 3.9 and PyCharm. Trying to execute from command prompt in Windows 10 Pro. I checked the environmental variables with the route to the folder where the executables are but still does not work.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are several ways to solve this. See the rules for setting [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). Your question doesn't specify which solution you want.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21203166) or one of these [PYTHONPATH and PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+PYTHONPATH)

Answer (score -1):

Use :

```
Python3 Helloword.py
```

Or:

```
Python Helloword.py
```

You have to tell to OS this is a python file. You just wrote file name but didn't tell what's execute this.

Comment: make sure to use lowercase `python` or `python3`

Comment: For Windows it doesn't matter

Comment: I don't use Windows, so I didn't know. But it's definitely good to lowercase everything because that's the standard for literally every other operating system, unless you alias it. Besides, it's one less keystroke for it, so why not?

Comment: @shark you're right.